# How to read and get $scope information in the angular controller after call query method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to read and get data from the angular $scope.var after to execute the query() method. I'm using .Factory to get information about the model.

this is my controller

```
var app = angular.module("appCtrl",[]);

app.controller('PersonController',['Person', '$scope',function(Person, $scope){
 $scope.person = Person.query();

 console.log($scope.person);
}]);
```

When I show the console.log in the chrome console, I show this.

[image]

But when a try to get the name attribute using

```
var app = angular.module("appCtrl",[]);

app.controller('PersonController',['Person', '$scope',function(Person, $scope){
 $scope.person = Person.query();

 console.log($scope.person.name);
}]);
```

Appear Undefined

[image]

How I get to name attribute from an angular Resource object ?

You help is very appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

am taking Person is a resource so at the moment of your console.log the promise attached to Person.query is not yet fulfilled, if wish to perform any operation after the query has finished you need to  pass in a callback function as a parameter meaning

```
Person.query(function(data){
     console.log(data.name);//assuming you are returning a person object
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Person being an angular resource returns a [promise](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/).

You can do like this

```
Person.query()
   .success(function(data){
        $scope.person = data;
        console.log($scope.person.name);
   })
   .error(function(data){
        //handle error here.
   });
```

There is a very good infographics about [promises](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html).